# TypeScript command-line compilation completes successfully but errors displayed

Tags: typescript, reactjs, typescript1.6

I was walking through the following JSX TypeScript tutorial: https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/jsx-intro

Using the `tsc.cmd -w` command, the following code compiles and executes successfully in the browser, but I still get errors in the console:

```
// app.tsx
var content = <div>Hello, world!</div>;

$(() => {
    let target = document.getElementById('output');
    React.render(content, target);
});
```

`

```
app.tsx(30,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'React'.
<br>app.tsx(34,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'React'.
<br>message TS6042: Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

`

Why do I still get errors even though the compilation succeeds? How to get rid of the errors?

I am using TypeScript 1.6

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I still get errors even though the compilation succeeds

Just because you get js from typescript does not mean *compilation* succeeds. Here's more on the topic : [Type errors do not prevent JavaScript emit](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html).

> How to get rid of the errors

You need the `react.d.ts` file (`tsd install react`) ([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/jsx/tsx.html))

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that TypeScript emits JavaScript even if there are compilation errors. You answer to my second question did not help though, as I already have the necessary typings installed as per following the steps in the linked article.

Comment: Since you are not using *external modules*. Use `tsd install react-global` to get the *global* version of react (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react-global.d.ts). That said I highly recommend you use file modules with something like weback. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html

Answer (score 0):

basarat answered my first question but I was still having issues the the compilation errors.

After looking at the errors again, I realized that the TypeScript compiler couldn't find *React* but It didn't seem to have a problem finding JQuery. So I opened up the React.d.ts file and sure enough, that was the problem. The React namespace was named `__React` instead of `React`. Aliasing the namespace like so

```
import React = __React;
```

allowed me to get rid of the TypeScript errors but unfortunately the app was then expecting to find a global variable called *__React*. But the React library downloaded from Bower had a variable called *React* as you would expect.

I added the following script after the including react script in the index.html file

```
<script>var __React = React;</script>
```

This allowed the app to run.

I am not sure why the type definition file had that namespace though or if I am getting around the issue the *right way*, but this solved my problem for now.

**Update**

I found a better way... Installing react-global `tsd install react-global` exposes the **React** namespace, making the above hack not required